# How to combine these two regex expressions?

Tags: regex

I have a string right here :

```
const text = "12-100 12-199 12-300 12-999 12-666coucou 12-555 1-678 12c-666 plop12-100 12-199 12-300 12-999 12-666"
```

And 2 regex expressions :

```
const regex1 = /(?<=coucou).*(?=plop)/g
const regex2 = /\d{1,2}-\d{2,3}/g
```

I just want to match 12-555 & 1-678 with a single RegExp.
How Can I replace this .* in the first expression please?

Thank you in advance for your answers and explanations!

Comment: Have you tried simply replacing the `.*` with the contents of the second expression?

Comment: Yeah, I already did. And It didn't work

Comment: ``const regex1 = /(?<=coucou.*)\d{1,2}-\d{2,3}(?=.*plop)/g``

Comment: Oh! I hadn't tried it this way. Thank you :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew which regex flavours allow variable length lookbehind?

Comment: @jhnc JavaScript, Python `regex`, .NET, Vim, and also ICU and Java support constrained-width lookbehind. Quite many. In PHP and Onigmo (e.g. Ruby), there is a known technique with `\G` and `\K` to extract multiple matches between two different patterns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
const regex = /(?<=coucou.*)\d{1,2}-\d{2,3}(?=.*plop)/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TJnfEJ/1).

JavaScript demo below:

```js
const text = "12-100 12-199 12-300 12-999 12-666coucou 12-555 1-678 12c-666 plop12-100 12-199 12-300 12-999 12-666"
const regex = /(?<=coucou.*)\d{1,2}-\d{2,3}(?=.*plop)/g
console.log(text.match(regex));
```